# Pass arguments (files) from python script to laravel artisan command

Tags: python, laravel

I want to pass two files from a python script to laravel artisan command, My python script:

```py
import subprocess

file1 = 'C:\\Users\\MyFolder\\Mybook.pdf';
file2 = 'C:\\Users\\MyFolder\\Myaudio.mp3';

subprocess.call("php C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\artisan zip " + file1 +' '+ file2 )
```

My command class:

```php
<?php

class ZipFiles extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'zip {file1} {file2}';

    protected $description = 'zip files';

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info($this->argument('file1'));

        Log::info($this->argument('file2'));
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

> Too many arguments to "zip" command, expected arguments "file1" "file2".

Comment: throw some quotes around those file names and see what happens

Comment: that is "generated" command my actual call is : `subprocess.call("php C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\artisan zip " + file1 +' '+ file2 )`

Comment: so put quotes around file1 and file 2 ... you can run this manually yourself to see as well, `php artisan zip "C:...." "C:..."` to see if it helps ... just trying to see if the filenames are breaking the way the parameters are interpretted

Comment: my files are dynamic i have to path it as variable, besides the quote around variable just passes variable name iteself not the full path `subprocess.call("php C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\artisan zip " +"file1"+' '+"file2")`

Comment: to test this the **OUTPUT** would have to have quotes around those 2 file names ... so again test this manually on the command line yourself or learn how to add quotes in a string

Comment: Can you send the codes ? i tried with quotes but not working

Comment: i don't use PYTHON I am a PHP developer `:)` ... so i guess you will have to learn how to add quotes to a string in python ... and this is just to do a test to help diagnosing .. so again for the 3rd time, test it from the command line directly

Comment: i actually tested it on command line `python index.py` and it throw php error `

    Too many arguments to "zip" command, expected arguments "file1" "file2".
`

Comment: you want to run this artisan command on the command line so that way you can figure out the correct way to get it to understand all the arguments correctly ...  just put quotes around the file names and see if that helps ... if it doesn't then on to the next diagnosis steps

Comment: Hey man i just search around the python quotes and i found that i have to use `f"{file1}"` that was my problem thanks for your help btw